# primefaces does not render f:selecteditems

Tags: primefaces, jboss, radio-button, seam

here is mycode: there might be some mistakes but I am doing right, I am thinking my problem is in Java code can you please throw some light, I am trying to render radio values.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="firstBill" value="#{myClass.myfee}" label="what to do?">
                        <f:verbatim>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{myClass.listMyFee}"/>
                        </f:verbatim>
                        </p:selectOneRadio>



@Name("myClass")
public class MyClass
{
private String fee;
 private Map<String, String> listMyFee;
public Myclass(){
//constructor
listMyFee = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
   listMyFee;.put("Yes", "Yes");
   listMyFee;.put("No", "No");

}

 public Map<String, String> getListMyFee()
  {
    return this.listMyFee;
  }


get and set for fee are written
```

Answer (score 0):

your bean-code is wrong, you need for `f:selectItems` a list of `List<SelectItem>`.

It would look like this:

```
List<SelectItem> list = new LinkedList<SelectItem>();
list.add(new SelectItem(<returnValue>, <displayValue>));
```

In your xhtml-file:

```
    <p:selectOneRadio id="firstBill" value="#{myClass.myfee}" label="what to do?">
          <f:selectItems value="#{myClass.list}" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
```